# Initial Camera Position Google Maps Compose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use the new Google Maps Compose functions to add a map, but I can't get it to set the initial camera position.  For testing purposes, the lat and lon are equal to Mountain View, CA, and zoom is 5:

```
GoogleMap(
        googleMapOptionsFactory = {
            GoogleMapOptions()
                .camera(
                    CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(
                        LatLng(lat.toDouble(), lon.toDouble()),
                        zoom.toFloat()
                    )
                )
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
```

It just shows a map with the camera centered at 0, 0.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I solved it, but it still leaves questions. The `googleMapOptions().camera` seems to be completely useless. I had to do this:

```
GoogleMap(
        cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
            position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(LatLng(lat.toDouble(), lon.toDouble()), zoom.toFloat())
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
```

That works, having the `googleMapOptions().camera` in there seems to do nothing at all, so I'm still confused as to its purpose.

Comment: `googleMapOptionsFactory` is primarily used for setting properties on the map that have to be done once when initializing the map (e.g. map ID, lite mode, etc.). I agree that this is confusing and have update the repo's README to clarify this https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/pull/51